# Unable to identify Button in hybrid page in android app appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, xpath, appium

I have tried to identify **'Send' button but Appium doesn't shown source of that page**. This page is a webpage in hybrid android app. Is there any way to get source of this button and verify/inspect it?

I have tried with chrome://inspect/#devices and able to inspect this button in Developer tools but don't know where verify? This is what DOM has inspected.

`<button id="btnSaveForm" type="button" ng-click="submitForm(1)" class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="isXhrPending() || mainCtrl.isAttachUploading">Send</button>`

What could be the Xpath of this and how do I verify it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *XPATH 1*:

  ```
  //button[@class='btn btn-danger' and @id='btnSaveForm'][text()='Send']
  ```
- Using *XPATH 2*:

  ```
  //button[@class='btn btn-danger' and @id='btnSaveForm'][starts-with(@ng-click, 'submitForm') and text()='Send']
  ```

Comment: none of them are working :-( Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //button[@class='btn btn-danger' and @id='btnSaveForm'][starts-with(@ng-click, 'submitForm') and text()='Send'] (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: these are way too narrow to select the element reliably imho. Things that would break these selectors: trailing space in classes, different class order, trailing space in text.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with dynamic rendering you should try to keep your xpath as simple as possible.

How about selecting by buttons function: `//button[contains(@ng-click,"submitForm")]`?

Answer (score 0):

For Hybrid apps automation, it's important to define the right context for Appium.

The default context is NATIVE_APP.

So Appium is not able to find any web-view element.

In order to switch context programmatically (with java) you can call

```
// the name could be WEBVIEW_... you have to print all the available contexts with driver.getContextHandles(); and find your one
driver.context("WEBVIEW_1");
```

or for appium java-client 8

```
import io.appium.java_client.remote.SupportsContextSwitching;

((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).context("WEBVIEW_1");
```

**Switch the context in Appium Inspector**

I cannot check this, but on your screenshot, there is **NATIVE_APP** text option in the right-middle part of the screen.

I guess it might be a dropdown with an additional `WEBVIEW_...` option, so this might be switched.

But when I've tried to find any documentation regarding context switching in Appium Inspector, I've found just this closed feature request (not implemented).

https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/issues/317

So, this might not be implemented and not supported by Appium Inspector.

In this case, try to follow the suggestion:

> You can test webviews by using Chrome or Safari inspector against sims/emus or real devices. Then you get a much more full-featured inspector than we could ever build in Appium Desktop ourselves.

---

**Use autoWebview=true**

If your app launched in webview by-default, you might define an additional capability for Appium:

```
autoWebview = true
```

which forcefully moves Appium directly into the webview context.

But this also might not work with Appium Desktop (due to https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/issues/317), and need to be checked.